Does jest.mocked(..) not work with overloaded functions?
I tried using it with a function that was overloaded. For example the list api on googleapis and it was not working.
Eg -
import { google } from 'googleapis';
jest.mock('googleapis', () => ({
  google: {
    auth: {
      OAuth2: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({
        setCredentials: jest.fn(),
      })),
    },
    gmail: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
      users: {
        messages: {
          list: jest.fn(),
          get: jest.fn(),
        },
      },
    }),
  },
}));


const mockedGmail = google.gmail({ version: 'v1' });
const listApiMock = jest.mocked(mockedGmail.users.messages.list)

Then,if I tried doing:
listApiMock.mockResolvedValue(...) // it will complain that it doesn't recognize mockResolvedValue
So had to do the following instead, which breaks type-safety.
const listApiMock = mockedGmail.users.messages.list as jest.Mock;
